# Java Map of References to Singletons

Tags: java

I'd like to create a map of singleton classes that I can access via a cross reference in order to respond to a specific request. I have the following implemented, but having trouble getting to an actual reference that I can call getInstance() on.

```
Map<Integer, Class<? extends Thing>> xref = new HashMap<Integer, Class<? extends Thing>>();
xref.put(1, ThingOne.class);
xref.put(2, ThingTwo.class);

Class<? extends Thing> t = xref.get(1);
```

Ultimately then do something like...

```
something.perform(arg1, arg2);
```

Can't figure out how to get from "t" to "something", or if that's possible given the way I have it coded.  I tried calling .cast(Thing.class).getInstance(), but got a Cast exception.  Also tried reflection to get the getInstance() method, but no luck there either.

It may be I'm going down the wrong path altogether. Given 1..n possible functions, any given instance of the solution may only require a subset of these.  In addition, I'd like to easily add/delete classes and manage the interface through config vs. a bunch of object instantiations at startup time.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why do you want a map of classes and not objects? Why don't you use Guice, or Spring, or something?

Comment: I'll take a look at Guice, thanks.  My thought was to have a table of singletons, based on some sort of index.  A particular function isn't instantiated until requested, which may be never in certain instances. I could easily make this a table of service objects as well, but in most installations only a few will be required, and that won't really be known until runtime.

Comment: Somehow a "map of singleton classes" sounds borderline absurd.  If you've go so many singletons that you need a map to keep them straight then you are seriously abusing the concept.

Comment: @HotLicks...you may be right.  I'm mainly playing around with some ideas on the most efficient way to allow a controller to map requests with services.  I could easily instantiate each service object and route accordingly.  But in most installations only a fraction of the possible services will be used, and that won't be known at compile time.  Better ideas certainly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your purpose in creating this map. From what you've written, it seems you could simply put static `getInstance()` methods, that return singletons, on each relevant class. Or even more trivial: put each shared instance as a static final field of its class.

If you must use a map, don't use an integer as a key. The class is the key, and its instance is the value. Something like:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>,Object> singletons = new HashMap<>();

public static synchronized <T> T getSingleton(Class<T> klass) {
    Object obj = singletons.get(klass);
    if (obj == null) {
        try {
            obj = klass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        singletons.put(klass, obj);
    }
    return klass.cast(obj);
}
```

The creation code there is icky and requires a public no-arg constructor. You could alternatively call via reflection a static, specifically named method on each class to create the desired instance ("createInstance"), which might be a bit more flexible, but when you do that, it once again asks why bother with the map, when you could call a method on the class directly?

One interesting possibility with the map is to supply functions to create instances. In Java 8 syntax (import `java.util.function.Supplier`):

```
private static final Map<Class<?>,Object> singletons = new HashMap<>();

public static synchronized <T> T getSingleton(Class<T> klass) {
    Object obj = singletons.get(klass);
    if (obj instanceof Supplier) {
        obj = ((Supplier<?>)obj).get();
        singletons.put(klass, obj);
    }
    return klass.cast(obj);
}

public static synchronized <T> void declareSingleton(Class<T> klass, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    if (Supplier.class.isAssignableFrom(klass)) {
        // prevent Supplier<Supplier<?>> weirdness;
        // could use separate maps if those are really needed
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    singletons.put(klass, supplier);
}

static {
    // add creation expressions for several classes;
    // instances will not be created until needed
    declareSingleton(ThingOne.class, () -> new ThingOne());
    declareSingleton(ThingTwo.class, () -> new ThingTwo(123));
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want but it might contain some ideas.

Edit: I've just realized a problem of using the Class itself as a key: it causes the class to be loaded even if it is not needed during a particular program run. Using a String key would avoid loading unneeded classes, but increases fragility. This is another argument against using a map for all this.

Comment: The key of the map is determined by the request...i.e. /request/thing/1 would look up index 1 of the "thing service table" to get the class that handles the request.  Essentially I'm trying to implement a service table without having to instantiate each handler.

Comment: @coolhouse Ah. You mean like.. web things? I don't know if I get it, but okay.